# Override WPFToolkit DatePickerTextBox control to Customized Combobox control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I want to use WPFToolkit DatePicker to insert date into my Combo box. By default, DatePicker comes with Text box for date. I know WPFToolkit has DatePickerTextBox Control for Textbox. I want to override it into ComboBox control. I don't know how to override this control.

I have a control which has some default parameters for date that is in combobox options such as One Year Ago, 2011, 2010, 2009, etc. When I select particular date from datepicker I want to display that date into combobox control.

I hope this question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to override this control directly. The only suggestion I can make is to play around with ElementName binding between that control and the ComboBox SelectedValue property to get the desired behavior.

After that if you are really determined you can replace the default style template for the DatePickerTextBox control to hide the TextBox element and put your ComboBox wherever you want in the UI making it appear to do what you want.

Comment: You are right. I did found my way to suffice my project requirements. Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found Calendar Control in WPFToolkit. I am using Calendar Control in MenuItem control with Combo box by side. It will be same as DatePicker control but instead of Textbox I will have Combo Box with other options in it.

It served my purpose of having ComboBox and DatePicker.